# AWS ECS - Task stuck running an inactive task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Very often when we update a task we got the old version of the task still running marked as in an inactive state. The only way to kill the old version is by stopping the container manually. According to the AWS team, this is happening because we still have connections attached to this old task. But how can we handle this behavior on services that have constant connections? I guess any kind of thread lock would cause similar behavior.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I experience the same from time to time. But it does not happen to all tasks. Still have not found a good solution. Maybe a Lambda function that gets triggered by your CI/CD pipeline and manually kills inactive tasks?

Answer (score 0):

AWS waits for your target group's "deregistration delay" before hard-killing any open connections.  Default is 300 seconds.  Maybe try lowering the value for deregistration delay and see if the "constant" connections you're referring to are forcefully killed more quickly.